# How are Spring boot @Async methods actually async/non-blocking?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, completable-future, spring-async

The following example is taken from [Spring' Getting Started Creating Asynchronous Methods.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

```
@Service
public class GitHubLookupService {

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<User> findUser(String user) throws InterruptedException {
    logger.info("Looking up " + user);
    String url = String.format("https://api.github.com/users/%s", user);
    User results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, User.class);
    // Artificial delay of 1s for demonstration purposes
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
  }

}
```

AFAIK my knowledge of async methods in computer science goes - **It should return immediately. It should be non-blocking.**

So lets say somewhere in Spring lets say my code `findUser()` is called like so:

```
CompletableFuture<User> user = service.findUser("foo");
```

This would actually block. **It would block a different thread on the `Executor` service but it would block due to the** `Thread.sleep(1000L)`. **Correct ?**

So how is this async ?

I mean the whole point of `CompletableFuture` is to get a reference to a computation that will be completed in the future. **But here when I get back the completed future the computation is already over, ie. we are using** `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results)`.

So what is the point of having a `CompletableFuture` in this case ? **I mean if I am going to block and return only when my computation is over and I have the results, I might as well just return the result and not the** `CompletableFuture`.

How is this truly non-blocking/async ?

The only non-blocking aspect I find here is **offload to a different thread, nothing else.**

Am I going wrong somewhere ? What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you create your `Future`. The code you use is

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results)
```

Quoting from the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), this is only a wrapper between sync and async, where the computation was done synchronously:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is already completed with the given value.

This is useful in certain situations where you only want to do asynchronous work for some inputs. Consider

```
(x) -> x==0 ? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0) : CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(expensiveComputation)
```

I hope this makes the difference clear - if you want truly async computations, you need to use the `supplyAsync` function:

> Returns a new `CompletableFuture` that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` with the value obtained by calling the given `Supplier`.

Comment: I did not write the code here. I got it from the Spring Docs.

Comment: This is inaccurate due to the Spring proxying magic going on behind the scenes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65488147/1108305.  Using `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results)` as used in this question is the idiomatic Spring `@Async` approach, and the end result is still an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 1):

The detail you're missing is that when `@Async` is used (and correctly configured), a proxy bean will be used, wrapping your service bean.  Any calls to the asynchronous methods through the proxy will use a Spring [`TaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) to asynchronously run the method.

Wrapping the method response in a synchronous `Future` such as `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` is necessary so the return type can be a `Future`.  However, the `Future` you return is not the one returned by the proxy.  Rather, the proxy returns a `Future` provided by the `TaskExecutor`, which will be processed asynchronously.  The `Future` you create through e.g. `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` is unwrapped by the proxy, and its completion result is returned by the proxy's `Future`.

## Proxying documentation

I don't see all of the aforementioned proxying details explicitly stated in either the [Spring reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) or in the [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.2/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) or [`@EnableAsync`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) Javadocs.  However, the details can be pieced together by reading between the lines of what is provided.

The `@Async` Javadocs mentions the service proxy in passing, and explains why `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` is used in the service method's implementation:

> A `Future` handle returned from the proxy will be an actual asynchronous `Future` that can be used to track the result of the asynchronous method execution. However, since the target method needs to implement the same signature, it will have to return a temporary `Future` handle that just passes a value through: e.g. Spring's `AsyncResult`, EJB 3.1's `AsyncResult`, or `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Object)`.

The fact that proxying is involved is also made apparent by the fact that two of the `@EnableAsync` annotation elements specify proxying details: [`mode`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html#mode--) and [`proxyTargetClass`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html#proxyTargetClass--).

## Question example

Finally, applying this to the question example will make it concrete.  Code that calls the `findUser` method on the `GitHubLookupService` bean will actually be calling a method on a proxy class, rather than directly on the `GitHubLookupService` instance.  The proxy class's `findUser` method submits a task to Spring's `TaskExecutor`, and return a `CompletableFuture` that will asynchronously be completed when the submitted task completes.

The submitted task will call the actual `findUser` method in the non-proxied `GitHubLookupService`.  This will will perform the REST call, sleep 1 second, and return a completed `CompletableFuture` with the REST results.

Since this task is happening in a separate thread created by Spring's `TaskExecutor`, the calling code will continue to proceed past the `GitHubLookupService.findUser` call immediately, even though it will take at least 1 second for it to return.

If the result of the `findUser` call is used in the calling code (using e.g. [`CompletableFuture.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get())), the value it will get from that `Future` will be the same `results` value passed to `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` in the `GitHubLookupService` code.